# CreateAsyncThunk Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am currently setting up my RTK (Redux Toolkit) and did some minor testings. Here's my code:

**store/index.js**

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { loginSliceReducer } from './views/page/login/loginSlice'

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    login: loginSliceReducer
  }
})
```

**loginSlice.js**

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import ApiService from '../../services/ApiService'

export const authorize = createAsyncThunk(
  'api/authorize',
  async (email, password) => {
    const response = await ApiService.post(email, password)
    return response.data
  }
)

export const loginSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'login',
  initialState: {
    loading: true,
    token: null,
    data: []
  },
  reducers: {
    updateState: (state, action) => {
      const { payload } = action
      switch (payload.type) {
        case AUTH_SUCCESS:
          state.loading = false
          state.token = payload.token
          state.data = payload.data
          break
        default:
      }
    }
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [authorize.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      // ... do state update here
    }
  }
})

export default loginSlice.reducer
```

**login.js**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { authorize } from './loginSlice'

const Login = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(authorize('testuser@example.com', 'test123'))
  }, [])

  return <div>Auth Test</div>
}
```

---

The code above doesn't work. I keep getting this error:

`Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

On this line:
`> 25 | dispatch(authorize('testuser@example.com', 'test123'))`

Please don't mind me triggering the authorize on *useEffect*, as this is only a test to check if the endpoint is being called and to check if the state will update once the request is successful. :-D

Comment: tagging @markerikson on my error. Please help

Comment: show us your code where you configure the store. Have you applied the `thunk` middleware?

Comment: I'll update the post

Answer (score 13):

I had this same issue and it was caused by the fact that I was adding additional middleware.

`@reduxjs/toolkit`'s `configureStore` has some middleware that is included by default, but if you add anything to the `middleware` property, it will overwrite these defaults.

The solution is to include the default middleware along with the middleware you define:

```js
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import { loginSliceReducer } from './views/page/login/loginSlice';
import { otherMiddleware } from './middlewares/some-other-module';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    login: loginSliceReducer
  },
  middleware: [ // Because we define the middleware property here, we need to explictly add the defaults back in.
    ...getDefaultMiddleware(),
    otherMiddleware
  ]
})
```

Note, there is no need to explicitly include `redux-thunk` when using `@reduxjs/toolkit` because it is already part of the default middlewares from `getDefaultMiddleware()`

Comment: this does not seem to be the solution to the OP question. I see how this could be valuable though for people who've accidentally overwritten their default middleware and are getting a similar error. The way RTK team suggests is to use the following ```middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware().concat(loggerMiddleware),
```
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that you didn't add to your store a middleware capable of handling async actions

In your `store/index.js` try smth like:

```
import { applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { loginSliceReducer } from './views/page/login/loginSlice'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    login: loginSliceReducer
  },
  middleware: [applyMiddleware(thunk), getDefaultMiddleware()]
})
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. By the way, here's my RTK version:
- reduxjs/toolkit@1.4.0
- redux@4.0.5
- redux-thunk@2.3.0
- redux-devtools@3.5.0

and I have this:
- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-redux@7.2.0
-  ERR! peer dep missing: react-redux@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0, required by redux-devtools@3.5.0

Comment: hm... maybe change the orders of middlewares so that thunk one goes first?  will update my code now...

Comment: sure! I'll try investigating further about this issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: any further luck @BenBorla ?

Comment: `redux-thunk` is included with RTK by default: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#simplifying-store-setup-with-configurestore

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one argument to be passed to an action creator, you must pass them inside an object.
For example, if I have to send email and password as payload, I will have to send them in an object like below:

```
dispatch(authorize({email, password}))
```

Answer (score 0):

one way you can fix this is to use your store's dispatch method.
This way, since thunk is included in Redux Toolkit (RTK) by default, you'll have access to that - which should fix the error you're getting.

Try This:

**store/index.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { loginSliceReducer } from './views/page/login/loginSlice'

export default const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    login: loginSliceReducer
  }
})

const useAppDispatch = () => store.dispatch

export { useAppDispatch }
```

**login.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import { authorize } from './loginSlice'
import { useAppDispatch } from './store/index'

const Login = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(authorize('testuser@example.com', 'test123'))
  }, [])

  return <div>Auth Test</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### This helped me!

###### getDefaultMiddleware is useful if you want to add some custom middleware, but also still want to have the default middleware added as well:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import logger from 'redux-logger'

import rootReducer from './reducer'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger),
})
```

The above solution is from official redux toolkit documentation:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware